# Excel Time Comparison and Subtraction

Tags: excel, time, excel-formula

I am trying to do a time subtraction in excel of 30 minutes and I am running into a speed bump. So the table I have are as follows.

```
Table "Schedule"
Column 1 is day of the week (Mon-Sun) (formated as general, as this is plain text)
Column 2 is start time of the shift (formated as h:mm AM/PM)
Column 3 is end time of the shift (formated as h:mm AM/PM)
Column 4 is duration of the shift (start to end) (formated by formula (TEXT(col3-col2,"h:mm")) )
Column 5 is paid hours (if the total hours is over 6.5 then subtract 0.5 hours for an unpaid lunch) (formula IF(col5>"6:30",col5-"0:30",D5) )
```

The issue is any time allotment over 10 hours start to end (where column 4, the duration hits 10 hours) no lunch is subtracted at all.

So...
Start 9:00 AM, End 6:59 PM, Hours Total 9:59, Hours Paid 9:29

But...
Start 9:00 AM, End 7:00 PM, Hours Total 10:00, Hours Paid 10:00

and that should obviously not happen. I can't find anything on google so I figured the excel gurus here may have some advice.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If your time columns are stores using excel's dedicated time format, this should be straightforward. Mixed data types are likely your problem.

First, be sure your time columns (columns 2 and 3) are set using the time function, i.e.,

=time(hours,minutes,seconds)

Then, you should be able to add and subtract easily.

Column 4:  = column 3 - column 2

... then subtract 30 minutes also using the time() function:

Column 5:  = if(column 4 > time(6,30,0),column 4 -time(0,30,0),column 4)

Comment: If the values in columns 2 & 3 are being typed in each time how can I have each cell set to be "=time(hours,minutes, seconds)"

Comment: You could type the time in across multiple columns and then refer to those columns (i.e., hour in column A, Minutes in column B, then use =time(A,B,0).

Comment: That maybe the only solution. It's just weird the formula would work up until 10 hours but not greater. I'm guessing there's some significance to 10 hours/600 minutes/3600 seconds and the way I'm formatting it

Comment: The important thing is that your time values are being stored as the time type - excel translates your time into an integer that it uses for calculations. I.e., 4:44 actually is stored as 0.197222. This makes it possible to do things like add and substract time. If columns 2 and 3 are always written exactly as HH:MM AM, and the format for the cells is set to Custom as h:mm AM/PM, then you don't need to use the time() function for these columns. You will still need to use time() for your IF logic and for the subtraction of 30 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Excel stores time values from 0 to 1. So 24 hours=1, 12 hours=.5 etc. That means 6.5 hours=0.270833333 and .5 hours=0.020833333. As a result you can just do a simple if statement.

```
=IF(D2>0.270833333,D2-0.020833333,D2)
```

To turn it into a time format, is to just use excel's time formating options.